# Request to App Engine Backend Timing Out

Tags: google-app-engine, backend

I created an App Engine backend to serve http requests for a long running process.  The backend process works as expected when the query references an input of small size, but times out when the input size is large.  The query parameter is the url of an App Engine BlobStore blob, which is the input data for the backend process.  I thought the whole point of using App Engine backends was to avoid the timeout restricts that App Engine frontends possess.  How can I avoid getting a timeout?

I call the backend like this, setting the connection timeout length to infinite:

`HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection());
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setConnectTimeout(0);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
    int ch;
    while ((ch = in.read()) != -1)
       json = json + String.valueOf((char) ch);
    System.out.println("Response Message is: " + json);
    connection.disconnect();`

The traceback (edited for anonymity) is:

`Uncaught exception from servlet
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching URL: http://my-backend.myapp.appspot.com/somemethod?someparameter=AMIfv97IBE43y1pFaLNSKO1hAH1U4cpB45dc756FzVAyifPner8_TCJbg1pPMwMulsGnObJTgiC2I6G6CdWpSrH8TrRBO9x8BG_No26AM9LmGSkcbQZiilhC_-KGLx17mrS6QOLsUm3JFY88h8TnFNer5N6-cl0iKA
        at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:142)
        at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:43)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.fetchResponse(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:417)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getInputStream(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:296)
        at org.someorg.server.HUDXML3UploadService.doPost(SomeService.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)`

As you can see, I'm not getting the DeadlineExceededException, so I think something other than Google's limits is causing the timeout, and also making this a different issue from similar stackoverflow posts on the topic.

I humbly thank you for any insights.

Update 2/19/2012: I see what's going on, I think. I should be able to have the client wait indefinitely using GWT [or any other type of client-side async framework] async handler for an any client request to complete, so I don't think that is the problem. The problem is that the file upload is calling the _ah/upload App Engine system endpoint which then, once the blob is stored in the Blobstore) calls the upload service's doPost backend to process the blob.  The client request to _ah/upload is what is timing out, because the backend doesn't return in a timely fashion.  To make this timeout problem go away, I attempted to make the _ah_upload service itself a public backend accessible via http://backend_name.project_name.appspot.com/_ah/upload, but I don't think that google allows a system service (like _ah/upload) to be run as a backend.  Now my next approach is to just have ah_upload immediately return after triggering the backend processing, and then call another service to get the original response I wanted, after processing is finished.

Comment: are you fetching from the backend from a front end instance? If so then I guess it's the frontend that's timing out, not the backend. If that's the case then try making the backend public and accessing the handler directly (as you are doing according to the URL in the trackback).

Comment: Paul, the request is coming from a public backend which I also have running.  I originally had the request coming from a frontend, but suspected this was the problem, so I moved it to the backend.  I stopped receiving hard deadline exceptions, but am still getting these timeouts.

Comment: Then I don't know, I work in the python side so I can't progress any further I'm afraid. As long as you are not triggering the request and then waiting for a response via a front end instance at any level (i.e. you should just be checking for updates via a handler that just returns status immediately regardless of the backends job status) then I'm at a loss.

Comment: Okay, maybe that is the problem.  I have a GWT client on a frontend uploader process that is waiting for all this to finish. I think it is an asynchronous GWT upload service.  I'll look at it closer and add more details soon.

Comment: That's got to be it then. Drop a value into memcache when your backend job completes and use the front end to check for that value (or datastore for more security) and of course don't wait for any backend process at any level directly in any sort of handler, just trigger them then return or check for status updates and return.

Comment: Okay, let me review this, and I might accept this as the answer, if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to start a backend process as a tasks and add that to the task queue, then returning a response to client before it waits to process the backend task (which can take a long time).  If I could have assigned ah_upload to a backend, this would have also solved the problem, since the clien't async handler could wait forever for the backend to finish, but I do not think Google permits assigning System Servlets to backends.  The client will now have to poll persisted backend process response data, as Paul C mentioned, since tasks can not respond like a normal servlet.